# Is it dangerous that both SSL Certificate and key got exposed to public?

Tags: security, ssl, webserver, admin

Before transferring our site's registered SSL certificate pair, I want to be sure of what would happen if both the SSL certificate and key file were to get stolen.  Would it be dangerous if some hacker were able to exploit our certificate with their own even though theirs won't be the same domain?

Comment: If the Private certificate (which includes the Key) is *ever* exposed / potentially-known then it must be invalidated as it is no longer insecure. Go to Jail (but really, just start over with *new* certificates so you *don't* end up getting in trouble). Do not pass go.

Comment: @user2864740 You mean the private key. There is no such thing as a 'private certificate', and he must start with a new *key-pair.*

Comment: @EJP Indeed; I was sloppy on the wording. Often "private certificate" seems to be tossed around to mean certificate+key, which is poor usage.

Comment: @user2864740 Never seen it, and I can't imagine why you would so use it. A certificate is inherently a public document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If your private key is compromised you must re-key and create new certificates. Otherwise the exploiter can impersonate you for legal purposes.

However the part of your question about 'exploit our certificate with their own' is meaningless.